# Remove Array from showing up on Index Template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently building an app in which I want to list all the reservations in a table on my index template. The problem is that, for every new reservation I generate, the array of data in each reservation shows up in my index template. For example

```
[#<Reservation id: 1, name: "john", guest_count: 3, min: 45, spent: 78  
tables: 4, status: "checked-in", server: "don Juan", added_by: "me", notes: 
"my notes">]
```

will show up on the top of my webpage when I load it. The rest of the webpage looks good however, I want to remove that part from loading on the webpage. 
My index view looks like this

**reservations/index.view.html**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Guest Count</th></th>
      <th>Min</th>
      <th>Spent</th>
      <th>Tables</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Server</th>
      <th>Added By</th>
      <th>Notes</th>
      <th colspan="9"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>



<%= @resos.each do |reso| %>
<tr>
<td><%= reso.name %></td>
<td><%= reso.guest_count %></td>
<td><%= reso.min %></td>
<td><%= reso.spent %></td>
<td><%= reso.tables%></td>
<td><%= reso.status %></td>
<td><%= reso.server %></td>
<td><%= reso.added_by %></td>
<td><%= reso.notes %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

and my reservations controller so far is

**reservations_controller.rb**

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  @resos = Reservation.all
  end

  def show
    @reso = Reservation.find_by(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @reso = Reservation.new(params_reso)
    @reso.save 

  end

   def new
     @reso = Reservation.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end


  private

  def params_reso
  params.require(:reservation).permit(:name, :guest_count, :min, :spent, :tables, :status, :server, :added_by, :notes)
  end


end
```

Once again, the table looks fine on the webpage. I just can't seem to get the array of all the reservation data off of the webpage. I am fairly new to rails, so have mercy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, using the 'equals' sign in the opening tag of the template is akin to calling `puts`.  Your invocation of `.each` is wrapped in a `puts` and returns whatever is in the current index as it iterates through them.  If you remove the equals sign in that line, you should only print what is wrapped in the iteration.

```
<% @resos.each do |reso| %>
```